# multi threaded find exec

Tags: find, xargs

Is there some mechanism to make find with -exec use multiple jobs?

Lets use this command for example

`find ./* -exec flac --best {} \;`

Is there some way to set the number of concurrent `-exec` commands to run easier than something like this solution:

run `find ./*` and save the results to a file/pipe them for another command to split into 16 parts (or however many threads you want) then run commands on these?

Comment: Pipe to xargs and use `-P`

Comment: Good call. This is what I ended up using:

```find ./* -type f -print0|xargs -0 -P 16 -I % opusenc --bitrate 256 % %.opus```

Comment: Nice! You can post that as an answer.

Comment: No need for the `./*`. A dot would be enough, and that would not blow up if you have many names in the current directory. I would also suggest a `-name` test to get names you want and not _everything_ (and `-type f` to avoid running `flac` (or `opusenc`) on directories).  If you have one single directory, you shouldn't need `find` at all, and if you're using `bash` or `zsh`, you could use `**` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the number of workers if you use xargs

```
find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 -P 16 -I % opusenc --bitrate 256 % %.opus
```

---

```
xargs -P 16
```

(since I struggled to find more details online or understand the man
page section)

It does your command on 16, or the number you pass to -P, of the
inputs at a time.

---

For my command I was trying to convert an organized folders of cd
music files [artist/album/music file] to opus. This was a copied
folder so I wanted to delete the originals. So a better command than
the one I used would be

```
find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 -P 16 -I % sh -c 'opusenc --bitrate 256 % %.opus && rm %'
```

After conversion the original file is removed.

Comment: a bit late, but for your "better" command consider changing the semicolon to `&&` so you don't go around removing source files that failed to convert!

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to also add stdout redirection with % replacement ? When I add >%.log.txt at the end of the command, the % is not replaced there. The output tries to go to "%.log.txt" and only the last process wins. I could use >> but that would get all lines mixed up since the processes are going in parallel.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop if you put the stdout redirection on the end of the opusenc command like this: `find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 -P 16 -I % sh -c 'opusenc --bitrate 256 % %.opus > %.log.txt && rm %'`

I suspect you may also want stderr though; use `find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 -P 16 -I % sh -c 'opusenc --bitrate 256 % %.opus > %.log.txt 2>&1 && rm %'` to do that